# Python JSON "column1=value1;column2=value2" to {"column1":"value1","column2":"value2"}

Tags: python, json, text

A really basic requirement.
I would like to convert from this format:

```
"column1=value1;column2=value2"
```

to this format (JSON):

```
{"column1":"value1","column2":"value2"}
```

Any best approach in Python would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

using regular expressions

```
import re

REGEX = r"([^=;]+)=([^=;]+)"
finder = re.compile(REGEX)

s = "column1=value1;column2=value2"

matches = re.finditer(finder, s)

d = {}
for match in matches:
    key = match.group(1)
    val = match.group(2)
    d[key] = val

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'column2': 'value2', 'column1': 'value1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to parse your string to JSON you should try something like this:

```
import json # simplejson if you use a python version below 2.6 

string = u'{"column1":"value1", "column2": "value2"}'
json = json.loads(string)
```

If you want to parse your string to a dictionary you should try ast:

```
import ast

string = u'{"column1":"value1", "column2": "value2"}'
ast.literal_eval(string)=>{'column1': 'value1', 'column2': 'value2'}
```

Comment: How this answer to the question ?